# Replace string between second set of [ and ]

Tags: javascript, regex

I am learning regex, and I got a doubt. Let's consider

```
var s = "YYYN[1-20]N[]NYY";
```

Now, I want to replace/insert the '1-8' between [ and ] at its second occurrence. 
Then output should be

```
YYYN[1-20]N[1-8]NYY
```

For that I had tried using `replace` and passing a function through it as shown below:

```
var nth = 0;
s = s.replace(/\[([^)]+)\]/g, function(match, i, original) {
    nth++;
    return (nth === 1) ? "1-8" : match;
});
alert(s); // But It wont work
```

I think that regex is not matchIing the string that I am using. 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You regex `\[([^)]+)\]` will not match empty square brackets since `+` requires at least 1 character other than `)`. I guess you wanted to write `\[[^\]]*\]`.

Here is a fix for your solution:

```js
var s = "YYYN[1-20]N[]NYY";
var nth = 0;
s = s.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/g, function (match, i, original) {
    nth++;
    return (nth !== 1) ? "[1-8]" : match;
});
alert(s);
```

Here is another way of doing it:

```js
 var s = "YYYN[1-20]N[]NYY";
var nth = 0;
s = s.replace(/(.*)\[\]/, "$1[1-8]");
alert(s);
```

The regex `(.*)\[\]` matches and captures into Group 1 greedily as much text as possible (thus we get the last set of empty `[]`), and then matches empty square brackets. Then we restore the text before `[]` with `$1` backreference and add out string `1-8`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex :

```js
 var s = "YYYN[1-20]N[]NYY";
var nth = 0;
s = s.replace(/([^[]+\[(?:[^[]+)\][^[]+)\[[^[]+\](.+)/, "$1[1-8]$2");
alert(s);
```

The first part `([^[]+\[([^[]+)\][^[]+)` will match a string contain first sub-string between `[]`. and `\[[^[]+\]` would be the second one which you want and the last part `(.+?)` match the rest of your string.

Answer (score 0):

If it’s only two occurences of square brackets, then this will work:

```
/(.*\[.*?\].*\[).*?(\].*)/
```

This RegEx has “YYYN[1-20]N[” as the first capturing group and “]NYY” as the second.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using simple `split` and `join` operations:

```
var s = "YYYN[1-20]N[]NYY";
var arr = s.split(/\[/)
arr[2] = '1-8' + arr[2]

var r = arr.join('[')
//=> YYYN[1-20]N[1-8]NYY
```